# gulp-replace doesn't use an exact match of the search string

Tags: node.js, regex, gulp, gulp-replace

I have these two Gulp tasks:

```
function changeAPIEnvDirectoryForProd() {
    return src('src/app/modules/models/ApiUrl.ts', { base: "src/app/modules/models/" })
    .pipe(replace('../../../environments/environment', '../environments/environment')).pipe(
        dest('src/app/modules/models/', {overwrite: true})
    );
}

function changeAPIEnvDirectoryForLocal() {
    return src('src/app/modules/models/ApiUrl.ts', { base: "src/app/modules/models/" })
    .pipe(replace('../environments/environment', '../../../environments/environment')).pipe(
        dest('src/app/modules/models/', {overwrite: true})
    );
}
```

Both run depending on the environment, one for production and the other for local development.

I'm having the issue that if in my file I have:

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment'

export class Apis {
    static bo = `${environment.boAPIUrl}/api/v1/bo`;
}
```

When I run the `changeAPIEnvDirectoryForLocal` task it replace the previous code with:

```
import { environment } from '../../../../../environments/environment'
```

This is because based on my code it should remain the same. I think the problem is for the replace search this two strings are the same:

```
../../../environments/environment
```

and

```
../environments/environment
```

Is there anyway to specify an exact match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to include the `'`'s in your search term like so:

```
.pipe(replace("'../environments/environment'", '../../../environments/environment'))
```

Now it will look for the full term only.  Escaping the `'`'s so tone `'` is included at the beginning and end of your search term also seems to work:

```
.pipe(replace('\'../environments/environment\'', '../../../environments/environment'))
```

By the way, your results are expected, gulp-replace will find `'../environments/environment` within `../../../../../environments/environment` because it is there.

Finally, you could use a regex with a positive lookbehind to solve your problem another way.  Such as

```
.pipe(replace(/(?<=')..\/..\/..\/environments\/environment/g, '../../../environments/environment'))
```

(in a regex your path separators would have to be escaped)

Comment: Thanks @Mark you are right, I ended up replacing the entire sentence: `import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment'` not only the path and it works.
Thanks